# define functions in haskell interactive shell

Tags: haskell

I want to do the following in `ghci`, but apparently it does not allow me to do so:

```
charName :: Char -> String  
charName 'a' = "Albert"  
charName 'b' = "Broseph"  
charName 'c' = "Cecil"
```

I could have done:

```
let charName 'a' = "Albert"  
let charName 'b' = "Broseph"  
let charName 'c' = "Cecil"
```

But still, because of no `charName :: Char -> String`, it would fail the following:

```
charName 'a' 
"*** Exception: <interactive>:38:5-26: Non-exhaustive patterns in function charName
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The reason your `charName 'a'` doesn’t work here is not because of a missing type signature. Instead, your three definitions of `charName` overwrite each other; at the end, `charName` is only defined for `'c'`, because that came last.

Comment: @chirlu: how can I define a type signature in `ghci`?

Comment: @QiangLi use a semicolon between it and the function, or better, use the :{ approach as in the linked duplicate, but it's actually far easier to just pop yoiur definitions in a file and load them, because they're easier to read and edit there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Braces and Semicolons instead of the white space rules:

```
Prelude> let {charName 'a' = "Albert"; charName 'b' = "Broseph"; charName 'c' = "Cecil"}
Prelude> charName 'a'
"Albert"
Prelude> charName 'b'
"Broseph"
```

Comment: thank you. Do you know how I can define a type signature in `ghci`?

Comment: @QiangLi: In the same way. Just don’t forget the `;` after it: `let { charName :: Char -> String; charName 'a' = ...`